# How many people are refused entry by the CBP?

Tags: usa, borders

An [old CBP leaflet](https://www.hsdl.org/?view&did=29068) says

> Based on fiscal year 2005 data on a typical day CBP processes 630,976 aliens [and] refuses entry of 868 non-citizens at our ports of entry

Is there a fresher set of data? This predates ESTA, a lot of information sharing and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [official summary](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/assets/documents/2016-Mar/CBP-Snapshot-031016-FY15.pdf) (as of March, 2016) Out of more than 1 million visitors/day, only 367 visitors are denied entry and deemed inadmissible, that's like **0.03%**. There's no mention of specific visa types.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3):

There are somewhat more recent numbers (~2010) about the ESTA and VWP program in [this GAO report](http://www.gao.gov/new.items/d11335.pdf) (ht: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-data-on-rejection-rates-of-the-visa-waiver-program)). Since these numbers measure something specific, they can't be compared to the 2005 figures above.

In 2010, 77,132 (0.24%) of ESTA applications were denied:

> - DHS denied 19,871 applications because of applicant responses to the  eligibility questions.
> - DHS denied 36,744 pending applications because of the results of manual  reviews of passenger data.
> - DHS denied 15,078 applications because the applicants had unresolved  cases of a lost or stolen passport that DHS decided warranted an
>     in-person  visa interview with a State consular officer.

So about half of the ESTA denials were for people ineligible to travel on the VWP in the first place or who had a potential issue with lost/stolen passports.

The report doesn't have rates for how many people denied ESTA were still able to get a US visa, but a footnote states that people are "frequently" able to get a visa.

In 2010, 6,486 VWP travelers arrived at the port of entry and were refused entry. According to [this chart](https://www.dhs.gov/sites/default/files/publications/ni_fr_2010.pdf) (I believe both data sources describe the same fiscal year), there were 14,821,569 + 2,256,611 = 17,078,180 admitted under the VWP that year. So that's a refusal rate at the border of 0.038%.

Note that these figures do not include non ESTA/VWP travelers refused entry.